# Debugging .NET framework source code

Tags: .net, debugging

I've already read some posts on SO re this issue but couldn't find a solution in them.

When I try to step into the .NET framework methods I get the message below on the output window.

- *"Step into: Stepping over method without symbols"*

But Modules window would show that "Symbols loaded" to the cache directory I have specified.

My Envinronment is as follows:

- Windows 7, 64 bit.
- VS 2008 .NET framework 3.5 SP1.

I have done the following already:

a)Toosl -> Options -> Debugging -> General

- Unchecked "Enable Just My Code"
- Checked "Enable source server
  support"
- Checked "Enable .NET framework source
  stepping"

b) Toosl -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

- Specified the symbols cache directory

Has this problem been fixed and a solution available? 
Appreciate if someone could throw a link at the KB describing the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A security update on Visual Studio might have caused that. Try reinstalling it (together with SP1). Just like here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/469279/net-framework-source-stepping-broken-in-vs2008-sp1

Comment: Thanks, saw that post earlier and didnt want to reinstall VS as I'm in the middle of some urgent work that I can't afford to delay. Is this the only workaround this issue? Thanks anyways.